# knockout writeable computed causes unnecessary 'read' calls

Tags: knockout.js, computed-observable

Computed read/write problem: 'write' causes 'read' execution.

I have read/write computed (or could also be pureComputed). It is writeable, because it could be computed from startDate and endDate. However, it could be also set directly, thus it is 'readable' and based on value startDate and endDate are set. Here is simplified version of my model:

```
 self.startDate = ko.observable(...);
 self.endDate = ko.observable(...);
 self.selectedTimePeriod = ko.pureComputed({
            read: function () {                
                console.log('time period read');
                var startDate = self.startDate(),
                    endDate = self.endDate(),
                    timePeriod = Enums.TimePeriodTypeEnum.None;
                timePeriod = Constants.MTD;                
                return timePeriod;
            },
            write: function (timePeriodValue) {
                console.log('time period write');
                switch (timePeriodValue) {
                    case Constants.MTD:
                        self.startDate(...);
                        self.endDate(...);
                        break;
                }
            }
    });

    self.timePeriodChange = function () {
        self.selectedTimePeriod(Constants.MTD);
    }
```

User click on UI triggers `self.timePeriodChange` function. As a result in console I see the following:

```
time period write
time period read
time period read
```

Thus, 'write' part is executed, however, when I change startDate and endDate - each time also 'read' part is executed. I see that this is because write updates read - but what if I do not wish this? How to deal with this situation?

The suggestion was to use peek, but this causes other problems (observable is not updated). 
Here is my fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/o5kacas3/ (changing dropdown, would not change computed on UI and actually its value, even when write part is executed).

Comment: That's because your `read` operation depends on the values of `startDate` & `endDate`, hence it's re-runs whenever those 2 changes. Try using `peek()` instead: `startDate = self.startDate.peek()` and `endDate = self.endDate.peek()`

Comment: Probably, this would help... However, if I use peek, then - if I change startDate or endDate outside 'write' operation, would it cause re-computation of observable?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll have to try and check

Comment: Another problem here is that if I use peek, then selectedTimePeriod() is never updating for some reason. For instance, if I just show it on UI it never updates (<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data.selectedTimePeriod, null, 2)"></pre>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing isn't actually a problem; it's how `write` works.

In the `read` method, knockout creates a *subscription* to any observable you evaluate. It needs to create these subscriptions so it can reevaluate *its own value* whenever another value it depends on changes.

If you use `obs.peek()` instead of just `obs()`, you can use a value without creating a subscription. This means your computed will not automatically update in the future.

In the `write` method, you're setting the observables that determine the `read` value. If you set 2 observables the computed relies on, you'll trigger 2 reads.

To illustrate: by setting the computed in the example below, and logging in between changes, you'll see the value actually change to "CB" briefly:

```js
var reads = 0;
var a = ko.observable("A");
var b = ko.observable("B");

// Read 0 is triggered by the computed itself: 
// it wants to know its initial value
var c = ko.computed({
  read: function() {
    // This line creates subscriptions to both `a` and `b`
    var value = a() + b();
    console.log("READ " + reads++ + ": " + value);
    return value;
  },
  write: function(str) {
    console.log("WRITE");
    
    a(str[0]); // Triggers read 1, since a changed
    
    // Momentarily, the value is 'CB'
    
    b(str[1]); // Triggers read 2, since b changed
  }
});

c("CD");
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** from the comments I now understand that it's essential to the op to not trigger multiple reads. The solution I proposed in the comments:

Rewrite the code to circumvent the writable observable:

```js
var a = ko.observable("A");
var b = ko.observable("B");

var getInitialValue = function() {
  return a() + b();
};

var createNewValues = function(str) {
  a(str[0]);
  b(str[1]);
};


var c = ko.observable(getInitialValue());
c.subscribe(createNewValues);


console.log(c()); // AB
c("CD");
console.log(c()); // CD
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see that this is how read/write works, but I do not need this. My question is - how to deal with this if I dont't want 'write' affecting 'read'? What would be the solution if I do not need this? I tried to use peek, but it causes problems that UI is not updated. This is my jsfiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/o5kacas3/

Comment: If you get rid of the `.peek()` everything works, doesn't it? Maybe you shouldn't use a writable computed but just specify a `setTimeRange` method that changes three observables: `timeRange`, `start` and `end`.

Comment: An example of how to circumvent the writable observable: https://jsfiddle.net/a6mz14s5/

Comment: I would try to understand if this fits my needs and introduc this solution then. It seems that it could work... One problem I see that in this case startDate and endDate changes would not affect timePeriod that was affected in the write/read solution.

Comment: That's a continuous struggle with the observable pattern: the more subscriptions and computeds you create, the harder it will be to keep track of the data flow and update count. Your initial solution works fine but might make some unneeded calculations; if you want to optimize for performance, you'll have to force some limitations into your code or at least do more stuff manually...

Comment: What about using [Deferred Updates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html)?

Comment: Great suggestion, wonder how I missed those... Seems like the perfect option for the case.

Comment: @MichaelBest, should I include it in my answer, or would you like to submit it as an answer yourself? Clearly, it's the better answer to the question...

Comment: I've added an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to avoid computing intermediate values in a computed is to use [deferred updates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html).

> Using deferred updates ensures that computed observables and bindings are updated only after their dependencies are stable. Even if an observable might go through multiple intermediate values, only the latest value is used to update its dependencies.
>
> When applied to a computed observable, the deferred extender will also avoid excess evaluation of the computed function. Using deferred updates ensures that any sequence of changes to dependencies in the current task will trigger just one re-evaluation of the computed observable.

```
self.selectedTimePeriod = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () { /*...*/ },
    write: function (timePeriodValue) { /*...*/ }
}).extend({ deferred: true });
```

Using this method, you'll see the following:

```
time period write
time period read
```